# Python Parallelism with GPIO and Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, python-multithreading

The goal of my program is to have the two checkboxes start independent yet parallel while loops. I considered threading but shouldn't the GIL prevent that from working? The loops need to be totally independent from one another. Also, the UI locks up. The longer the `.sleep` in the loop, the longer the lockup is. I figured that could be the problem because it might prevent it from working if they ever reached to update `top` at the same time, but without those `top.update`, the code stops working entirely when I start one of the loops. How can I achieve the parallelism I'm looking for?

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pinlist = [18, 23]

for i in pinlist:
    GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)

def CButtoncmd1():
    while(ActivateVar1.get()):
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
        top.update()
        time.sleep(.5);
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
        top.update()
        time.sleep(.5);

def CButtoncmd2():
    while(ActivateVar2.get()):
        GPIO.output(23, GPIO.LOW)
        top.update()
        time.sleep(.5);
        GPIO.output(23, GPIO.HIGH)
        top.update()
        time.sleep(.5);

top = tkinter.Tk()

ActivateVar1 = DoubleVar()
CButtonActivate1 = CheckButton(top, text="start1", variable=ActivateVar1, command=CButtoncmd1)
CButtonActivate1.pack()

ActivateVar2 =DoubleVar()
CButtonActivate2 = CheckButton(top, text="start2", variable=ActivateVar2, command=CButtoncmd2)
CButtonActivate2.pack()

top.mainloop()

Light1 = multithreading.Process(target=CButtoncmd1, name="Light1")
Light2 = multithreading.Process(target=CButtoncmd1, name="Light2")
Light1.start()
Light2.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter already implements its own processing loop.  You simply need to use your existing TK variables (or set other variables via the command callbacks) to tell a thread what state you're in.  The GPIO updates can then be done via the thread.  Take a look at the following example..

```
import time
import Tkinter as tkinter
import threading

def lightControl(lnum, blink_var):
    global run
    while run:
        if blink_var.get():   # blink
            print lnum, ' on'
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print lnum, ' off'
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            time.sleep(0.1)

def CButtoncmd1():
    print 'Button1 changed state to ', ActivateVar1.get()

def CButtoncmd2():
    print 'Button1 changed state to ', ActivateVar2.get()

top = tkinter.Tk()

ActivateVar1 = tkinter.DoubleVar()
CButtonActivate1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(top, text="start1", variable=ActivateVar1, command=CButtoncmd1)
CButtonActivate1.pack()

ActivateVar2 = tkinter.DoubleVar()
CButtonActivate2 = tkinter.Checkbutton(top, text="start2", variable=ActivateVar2, command=CButtoncmd2)
CButtonActivate2.pack()

# Run threads to monitor the state variables and set the lights
run = True
t1 = threading.Thread(target=lightControl, args=(1, ActivateVar1))
t1.daemon = True
t1.start()
t2 = threading.Thread(target=lightControl, args=(2, ActivateVar2))
t2.daemon = True
t2.start()

# Run tkinter's main loop
top.mainloop()

# Exit when the tkinter loop exits
print 'Exiting program'
run = False
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

There is no need to use multiprocessing for this.  Python's `threading` module will work fine and is much simpler because it doesn't require special code to share variables.  Multiprocessing is only needed when you need to engage multiple cores (The GIL locks you to a single core).  Here `threading` services all the various threads in a round-robbin fashion.  Since you're sleeping in these loops, you're not eating up much CPU time and `threading` works fine.

Comment: Hey Thank you so much. I had to modify the code a little, specifically I added a second light control function, and then changed the second thread to control that function. Also, thanks for showing me how to close the program properly.